# Fast MouseMove in label in VB6

Tags: vb6

`lblRoom` is control array of labels and `brdrRoom` is control array of shapes, On double click over each label, we can drag it with mouse. When one label move slowly over others there is no problem, it moves smooth, but when mouse move fast and when reach on center of other labels it gets moves and selected label goes stationary.
Code segment for `MouseMove` is given as:

```
Private Sub lblRoom_MouseMove(Index As Integer, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    SelectedItemIndex = Index
    XPos = lblRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Left + X
    YPos = lblRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Top + Y
    If DragItem = True Then
       lblRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Left = XPos - lblRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Width / 2
       lblRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Top = YPos - lblRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Height / 2
       brdrRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Left = XPos - brdrRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Width / 2
       brdrRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Top = YPos - brdrRoom(SelectedItemIndex).Height / 2
    End If
End Sub
```

What is the problem ? Help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move overtop another label, it's getting `MouseMove()` events as well and so your procedure is presumably switching the `SelectedItemIndex` between your two labels.

To fix this, you should ignore mouse events from other labels besides the one you're dragging. For example:

```
Private m_intDragIndex As Long

Private Sub lblRoom_DblClick(Index As Integer)
    m_intDragIndex = Index
End Sub

Private Sub lblRoom_MouseMove(Index As Integer, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    ' Only process events from the label that was double-clicked...
    If Index <> m_intDragIndex Then Exit Sub

    ...

End Sub
```

You haven't said when the drag should stop, but whatever you're doing to *end* the drag, make sure to set `m_intDragIndex = -1` or some other "invalid" value.